# HTML, CSS - how i transfer <a> style to ActionLink

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a CSS that I downloaded and it has a beautiful menu with styling for link, `hover`ing etc.

Since i develop in MVC i use

```
@Html.ActionLink("דף הבית", "Index", "Home", null, new { id = "something" }
```

I am very confused what in the CSS makes the menu.
How can I understand it and "translate", so it will apply to `HTML.ActionLink` instead of

```
<a href="#"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><span class="t">Menu Item</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can put all styling in a class then give class to ActionLink

```
   @Html.ActionLink("דף הבית", "Index", "Home", null, new { id = "something", @class="something you give to anchor" }
```

For example

```
a,.anchorstyle{
text-decoration:none;
color:blue;

}

<a href="#">hello </a>
```

or

```
<a class="anchorstyle" href="#">hello </a>
```

or
add this class to ActionLink

```
   @Html.ActionLink("דף הבית", "Index", "Home", null, new { id = "something", @class="anchorstyle" }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.ActionLink("דף הבית", "Index", "Home", null, new { id = "something", @class="someCssClass" }
```

OR

```
@Html.ActionLink("דף הבית", "Index", "Home", null, new { id = "something", @class="someCssClass", @style="color:white;" }
```